# How to tune a query with aggregations of tables over 15 million rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

The execution time of this query is 3:29 minutes. How is it possible to reduce execution time of this query?

The overall quantity of rows of `FactLoad` table is    - 16 769 952.

The overall quantity of rows of `FactLoadFin` table is - 12 308 763.

```
SELECT    
 wd.id_CompanyOperator AS IdCompanyOperator
, wd.StationFromCode
, wd.StationToCode
, SUM(wd.TariffInvRFPartialSum)/ MAX(wd.CarsCountByOp) AS TariffInvRFWeighted
, SUM(wd.TariffOwnRFPartialSum)/ MAX(wd.CarsCountByOp) AS TariffOwnRFWeighted
, SUM(wd.AmountIncVATPartialSum)/ MAX(wd.CarsCountByOp) AS AmountIncVATWeighted
, MAX(wd.AmountIncVAT) AS MaxAmountIncVAT
, MIN(wd.AmountIncVAT) AS MinAmountIncVAT
FROM      
(
    SELECT 
    AVG(fl.TariffInvRF) OVER (PARTITION BY fl.StationFromCode, 
                                        fl.StationToCode,
                                        fl.id_CompanyOperator,
                                        fl.NaklID)
                * COUNT(fl.ID) OVER (PARTITION BY fl.StationFromCode,
                                        fl.StationToCode,
                                        fl.id_CompanyOperator,
                                        fl.NaklID) AS TariffInvRFPartialSum
    , AVG(fl.TariffOwnRF) OVER (PARTITION BY fl.StationFromCode,
                                        fl.StationToCode,
                                        fl.id_CompanyOperator,
                                        fl.NaklID)
                * COUNT(fl.ID) OVER (PARTITION BY fl.StationFromCode,
                                    fl.StationToCode,
                                    fl.id_CompanyOperator,
                                    fl.NaklID) AS TariffOwnRFPartialSum
    , COUNT(fl.ID) OVER (PARTITION BY fl.StationFromCode,
                                fl.StationToCode,
                                fl.id_CompanyOperator) AS CarsCountByOp
    , AVG(flf.AmountIncVAT) OVER (PARTITION BY fl.StationFromCode,
                                        fl.StationToCode,
                                        fl.id_CompanyOperator,
                                        fl.NaklID) AS AmountIncVAT
    , AVG(flf.AmountIncVAT) OVER (PARTITION BY fl.StationFromCode,
                                        fl.StationToCode,
                                        fl.id_CompanyOperator,
                                        fl.NaklID)
                * COUNT(fl.ID) OVER (PARTITION BY fl.StationFromCode,
                                    fl.StationToCode,
                                    fl.id_CompanyOperator,
                                    fl.NaklID) AS AmountIncVATPartialSum
    , fl.StationFromCode
    , fl.StationToCode
    , fl.id_CompanyOperator
    , fl.NaklID
    FROM   dbo.FactLoad fl LEFT JOIN dbo.FactLoadFin flf 
        ON flf.id_FactLoad = fl.ID
           AND flf.id_Assortment IN (
               SELECT
               ID
               FROM  dbo.SP_Assortment WHERE Name IN ('Car Rent'))
    ) wd
 GROUP BY  wd.StationFromCode
    , wd.StationToCode
    , wd.id_CompanyOperator
```

[The query plan could be seen here.](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyRHJKot7)

The DDL of `FactLoad` is:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.FactLoad
(
     ID                     BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1)    NOT NULL      
   , NaklID                 BIGINT                  NOT NULL
   , CarNumber              VARCHAR(10)             NOT NULL
   , OutDate                    DATETIME                NOT NULL
   , ArriveDate             DATETIME                NULL
   , DeliveryDate           DATETIME                NULL
   , RegisterDate           DATETIME                NULL      
   , StationFromCode            VARCHAR(6)              NOT NULL
   , StationToCode          VARCHAR(6)              NOT NULL
   , Distance               INT                     NULL
   , DistanceRF             INT                     NULL
   , ETSNG                  VARCHAR(6)              NOT NULL
   , id_RouteType           INT                     NULL
   , id_RouteView           INT                     NULL
   , CarQnt                 INT                     NOT NULL
   , CarCapacity                NUMERIC(7,3)            NULL
   , CarModel               VARCHAR(50)             NULL
   , CarType                    INT                     NOT NULL
   , CargoWeight                NUMERIC(7,3)            NULL
   , OwnerOKPO              VARCHAR(12)             NULL
   , TenantOKPO                 VARCHAR(12)             NULL
   , SpecialNotes           VARCHAR(25)             NULL
   , TariffInv              NUMERIC(18,3)           NULL
   , TariffInvRF                NUMERIC(18,3)           NULL
   , TariffOwn              NUMERIC(18,3)           NULL
   , TariffOwnRF                NUMERIC(18,3)           NULL
   , Operator1              VARCHAR(255)            NULL
   , Operator2              VARCHAR(255)            NULL
   , isDeleted              TINYINT                 NULL DEFAULT(0)
   , DeleteDate             DATETIME2               NULL
   , NeedUpdate_Data            TINYINT                 NOT NULL DEFAULT(0)
   , NeedUpdate_Tariff      TINYINT                 NOT NULL DEFAULT(1)
   , NeedTransffer          TINYINT                 NOT NULL DEFAULT(1)
   , id_FactLoad                BIGINT                  NULL
   , DepartureDate          DATETIME                NULL
   , DepartureDateSuek      DATETIME                NULL
   , id_CompanyOperator     INT                     NOT NULL DEFAULT(-1)
   , StationBorderInCode        VARCHAR(6)              NULL
   , StationBorderInDate        DATE                    NULL
   , TariffVAT              NUMERIC(21,3)           NULL
   , CarSign                    VARCHAR(50)             NULL
   , CONSTRAINT [PK_FactLoad] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID) WITH( 
   STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
   ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_FactLoad_NaklIDLast] ON dbo.FactLoad(NaklID_Last)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_FactLoad_NaklnumberCarnumberOutdate] ON dbo.FactLoad(NaklNumber, CarNumber, OutDate)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_FactLoad_ForTariff] ON dbo.FactLoad(OutDate, ETSNG, NeedUpdate_Tariff, CarType, Distance, DistanceRF, StationToCode, StationFromCode, CargoWeight, id_RouteView, CarQnt, CarCapacity, CarModel)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_FactLoad_ForTariff_2] ON dbo.FactLoad (NeedUpdate_Tariff, CarType) INCLUDE (Distance, DistanceRF, ETSNG)

ALTER INDEX [IX_FactLoad_ForTariff_2] ON [dbo].[FactLoad] DISABLE



 IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = 
     object_id('dbo.FactLoad') AND NAME ='IX_FactLoad_ForObjectsID4Transfer')
 DROP INDEX [IX_FactLoad_ForObjectsID4Transfer] ON dbo.FactLoad;

 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_FactLoad_ForObjectsID4Transfer] ON 
      dbo.FactLoad (NaklID, OutDate, NeedUpdate_Tariff, ModifyDate)


 IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = object_id('dbo.FactLoad') AND NAME ='IX_FactLoad_ForObjectsID4Transfer_2')
 DROP INDEX [IX_FactLoad_ForObjectsID4Transfer_2] ON dbo.FactLoad;

 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_FactLoad_ForObjectsID4Transfer_2] ON 
     dbo.FactLoad (NaklID_Last, OutDate, NeedUpdate_Tariff, ModifyDate)



  CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_FactLoad_ForResetStatus] ON dbo.FactLoad 
      (ModifyDate) INCLUDE (NaklID, NaklID_Last)


  CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_FactLoad_ForIsDeleted] ON dbo.FactLoad 
      (OutDate,isDeleted,SourceFlag) INCLUDE ([ID],[NaklID],[NaklNumber], 
      [CarNumber],[ArriveDate],[DeliveryDate],[StationFromCode], 
      [StationToCode],[DistanceRF],[ETSNG],[id_RouteType],[CarQnt], 
      [CarCapacity],[CarModel],[CargoWeight],[OwnerOKPO],[TenantOKPO], 
      [TariffInvRF],[TariffOwnRF],[SenderOKPO],[RecipOKPO], 
      [PayerOKPO],[StationBorderCode],[DateExpire],[CarWeight],[DueWeight], 
      [Weight1001],[DailyOrderNum],[DailyOrderPos],[DistanceDue], 
      [id_SolidThread],[DepartureDate],[id_CompanySender],[id_CompanyRecip], 
      [id_Incoterms],[isSuek],[id_CompanyPayer],[OwnerID],[TenantID], 
      [id_CompanyOwner],[id_CompanyTenant],[ArriveDateReceiver], 
      [id_CompanyBeneficiary],[id_CompanyOperator],[SAP_CargoCode], 
      [SAP_SenderPE],[id_VAT],[LastNaklNumber],[LastCarNumber],[isDos], 
      [PriorETSNG])


  CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_FactLoad_LastnaklnumberLastcarnumberOutdate] 
  ON dbo.FactLoad (LastNaklNumber, LastCarNumber, OutDate)


  CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_FactLoad_CarnumberNaklnumberOutdate] ON 
     [dbo].[FactLoad] ([CarNumber], [NaklNumber], [OutDate]) ON [PRIMARY]


  CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_FactLoad_StationFromTo] ON [dbo].[FactLoad] 
      ([StationFromCode], [StationToCode])
```

The DDL of `FactLoadFin` is:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.FactLoadFin
   (
    ID                              BIGINT              NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
  , id_FactLoad                     BIGINT              NOT NULL
  , id_Assortment                   INT                 NOT NULL
  , id_AccrualType                  TINYINT             NOT NULL
  , id_Company                      INT                 NOT NULL
  , SpecItem                        INT                 NULL
  , id_VAT                          INT                 NULL
  , Amount                          NUMERIC(18,2)       NULL
  , AmountVAT                       NUMERIC(18,2)       NULL
  , AmountIncVAT                    NUMERIC(18,2)       NULL
  , ActItem                         BIGINT              NULL
  , Scope                           VARCHAR(5)          NULL    
   ) 

 drop index if exists FactLoadFin.IX_FactLoadFin_ActitemIddocumentheader
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_FactLoadFin_ActitemIddocumentheader ON 
     dbo.FactLoadFin(ActItem, id_DocumentHeader)

 drop index if exists FactLoadFin.IX_FactLoadFin_Iddocumentheader
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_FactLoadFin_Iddocumentheader ON 
 dbo.FactLoadFin(id_DocumentHeader)

 drop index if exists FactLoadFin.IX_FactLoadFin_Assortment
 create index IX_FactLoadFin_Assortment on FactLoadFin
    (id_Assortment, id_Contract, id_Company, id_FactLoad);
 update statistics FactLoadFin with fullscan;

 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_FactLoadFin_idContractDoc_SpecItem] ON 
    dbo.FactLoadFin(id_ContractDoc, SpecItem) INCLUDE (id_DocumentHeader, 
    Amount, AmountVAT, AmountIncVAT)

 DROP INDEX IX_FactLoadFin_ScopeAmount ON dbo.FactLoadFin
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_FactLoadFin_ScopeAmount] ON 
     dbo.FactLoadFin(Scope, Amount) INCLUDE(id_FactLoad, id_Contract, 
     id_Company, ActItem, AmountVAT)
```

I've reduced columns in `CREATE TABLE` to make it shorter as reduced columns are not participated in a query to be tuned.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I believe it is better to ask question and be advised by community, than to be without knowledge all time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We're going to need the Query plan ([Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)) and the DDL of your table to help you here.

Comment: @MJH OP has edited. it said seconds before. :) There's quite a big 3 and a half minutes and 3.3 seconds :)

Comment: I can't see anything that is going to specifically make the query non-SARGable. I would suggest, however, changing `cf.id_Assortmen IN {SubQuery}` to an `EXISTS`.

Comment: [Google - Define: DDL](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A+DDL&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b)

Comment: @StepUp This link should help you:  https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Thanks, we really need the definitions of the indexes as well please. :)

Comment: @Larnu I've attached a query plan and DDL with indexes. Thanks in advance. Is it possible to decrease execution time it without altering index?

Comment: Your index statements have column names that do not exist the in the table DDL

Comment: @JM I've reduced columns in `CREATE TABLE` to make it shorter. Is it necessary to add all columns?

Comment: Have you tried using columnstore indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your plan it seems that most resources are eaten by sort operation:
[image]

[image]

I would probably create the following index in order to have this data pre-sorted:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_FactLoad_StationFromCode_StationToCode_idCompanyOperator_NaklID
ON dbo.FactLoad (StationFromCode, StationToCode, id_CompanyOperator, NaklID)
INCLUDE (TariffInvRF, TariffOwnRF, ID);
```

This should improve it, but probably won't do miracles. If it does - this can be looked at further and investigated more.

**Update:**

Try to use `ColumnStore` index.

Measurements with `ColumnStore` index.

> `ColumnStore` index with including Actual Execution Plan: 01:02
>   minutes, WITHOUT including Actual Execution Plan is: 01:01 minutes.

The code of `ColumnStore` index is

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX 
   [csi_FactLoad_StationFromCode_StationToCode_idCompanyOperator_NaklID] ON 
   [dbo].[FactLoad] ( [NaklID], [StationFromCode], [StationToCode], 
   [id_CompanyOperator], [ID], [TariffInvRF], [TariffOwnRF] )WITH 
   (DROP_EXISTING = OFF, COMPRESSION_DELAY = 0) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've added an index `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_FactLoad_StationFromCode_StationToCode_idCompanyOperator_NaklID] ON [dbo].[FactLoad]
(
 [NaklID] ASC,
 [StationFromCode] ASC,
 [StationToCode] ASC,
 [id_CompanyOperator] ASC
)
INCLUDE (  [ID],
 [TariffInvRF],
 [TariffOwnRF]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO`. The execution time is 3:39 minutes. The query plan is https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJgUmjiFm

Comment: Heya, order of indexed columns is incorrect - `NaklID` was moved to beginning instead of the end. So sort operation is still there and there's no perf improvement.

Comment: `ColumnStore` index  with including `Actual Execution Plan`: `01:02 minutes`, WITHOUT including `Actual Execution Plan` is: `01:01` minutes. The code is ``CREATE NONCLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX [csi_FactLoad_StationFromCode_StationToCode_idCompanyOperator_NaklID] ON [dbo].[FactLoad]
(
 [NaklID],
 [StationFromCode],
 [StationToCode],
 [id_CompanyOperator],
 [ID],
 [TariffInvRF],
 [TariffOwnRF]
)WITH (DROP_EXISTING = OFF, COMPRESSION_DELAY = 0) ON [PRIMARY]``

Comment: That's better. also try copying index from my answer and creating that exact index. :)

Comment: The execution time of NONClustered index is: `02:59 minutes`
`CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_FactLoad_StationFromCode_StationToCode_idCompanyOperator_NaklID1
ON dbo.FactLoad (StationFromCode, StationToCode, id_CompanyOperator, NaklID)
INCLUDE (TariffInvRF, TariffOwnRF, ID);`

Comment: Good enough, so columnstore index seems to work best. :)

Comment: Thank you for your advice to use `ColumnStore` index! But why `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_FactLoad_StationFromCode_StationToCode_idCompanyOperator_NaklID1 ON dbo.FactLoad (StationFromCode, StationToCode, id_CompanyOperator, NaklID) INCLUDE (TariffInvRF, TariffOwnRF, ID);` did not improve performance?

Comment: Well, you should look at execution plan. Probably sort operation still had to be made.